# Flutter - How to expand a widget with animation?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, dart

So I have the following code

```
Row(
  children: [
    IconButton(), // IconButton1
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: Textfield(),
      ),
    ),
    IconButton(), // IconButton2
  ]
)
```

When I type in something in the textfield, I want the IconButton1 to be removed and the textfield container or the textfield itself to expand with an animation to take the space of that IconButton1. I am able to do this but I can not do it with an animation.

I tried AnimatedContainer and AnimatedSwitcher but they didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple container you should use AnimatedContainer.
Else you should use [scale transition](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScaleTransition-class.html).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  final items = List<int>.generate(20, (i) => i + 1);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Dismissing Items';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = items[index];
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(item.toString()),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                setState(() {
                  items.removeAt(index);
                });

                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(
                    content: Text('$item dismissed'),
                  ),
                );
              },
              background: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                height: 1200 / items.length,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                child: Text('$item'),
                color: (items[index] % 2 == 0) ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `width` of the `Container` is not defined inside the `Container`. The `Container` is put in the `Expanded` widget so that it takes the width that it can. Now the thing is, when i remove one of the Component in the row, the "Expanded" expands the container. This is where I want some sort of animation because as of now, it just expands without any animation as expected.

Comment: check the code, I have edited my answer with a code snippet.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I am looking for. If you read my question, you can see that I want 2 IconButtons, a textfield, 1 more IconButton, these 4 elements in a row. And as I type something in the textfield, the first 2 IconButtons should disappear and the textfield should expand horizontally to take the space of those 2 IconButtons which are removed. You can also check the code I provided so that you understand the Widget tree that I want to build.